# Arcane strike feat damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

The *Arcane Strike* feat states that as a free action, you can sacrifice one spell to add +1 to hit and 1-4 damage per spell level on your weapon for one round. I've seen it stated on other boards ([example](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?193184-Can-you-stack-arcane-strike-with-itself)) that since it's a free action, you could add as many spells to the attack as you want, with the attack bonus not stacking, only the highest spell bonus to hit as your highest spell level but stacking all the 1-4 damage dice.

For example, sacrificing two 5th level and five 2nd level spells would grant +5 to hit and +20d4 damage.

How does this really work?

Comment: Can you link to those discussions on other boards?

Comment: Let's have the link to the original statements before we try to explain how what they are saying is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is firmly in "ask your DM" territory.

The basis for this claim is the wording of [the rules for stacking modifiers](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm).  Those rules state:

> In most cases, modifiers to a given check or roll stack (combine for a cumulative effect) if they come from different sources and have different types (or no type at all), but do not stack if they have the same type or come from the same source (such as the same spell cast twice in succession). If the modifiers to a particular roll do not stack, only the best bonus and worst penalty applies. Dodge bonuses and circumstance bonuses however, do stack with one another unless otherwise specified.

The *Arcane Strike* feat provides two different benefits when you sacrifice spell slots:  A bonus to your attack rolls, and extra damage dice.  The relevant wording is:

> ...you gain a bonus on all your attack rolls for 1 round equal to the level of the spell sacrificed, as well as extra damage equal to 1d4 points x the level of the spell sacrificed. The bonus you add to your attack rolls from this feat cannot be greater than your base attack bonus.

The glossary (PHB p. 310) defines "modifier" as:

> Any bonus or penalty applying to a die roll. A positive modifier is a bonus, and a negative modifier is a penalty. Modifiers from the same source do not stack, and modifiers with specific descriptors generally do not stack with others of the same type. If more than one modifier of a type is present, only the best bonus or worst penalty in that grouping applies. Bonuses or penalties that do not have descriptors stack with those that do.

Since the extra damage dice are not explicitly worded as a "bonus," some DMs argue that they are not a "modifier to a given check or roll," and that the stacking rules therefore don't apply.

---

Many DMs, this answerer included, rule that the extra damage from *Arcane Strike* is, in fact, a bonus, defined (PHB p. 305) as:

> A positive modifier to a die roll...

It does, after all, modify your damage roll, and it does so positively.  In this case, neither the attack bonus nor the extra damage dice would stack.

However, as the text of *Arcane Strike* does not *explicitly* call the damage dice out as "bonus damage," reasonable DMs may disagree.